# How to create model's tables in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to replicate a PHP/Symfony project in Python/Django as a python learning exercise. Platform = Windows 10. The expected result is that a `migrate` command will add tables related to all of the entries in `settings.py INSTALLED_APPS{...}`. Instead, the `migrate` command adds all `Django` tables but none of the tables of `models.py`.

What, then, must be done to allow `migrate` to add the 5 MySQL tables?

Result:

```
mysql> use diet_py;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_diet_py          |
+----------------------------+
| auth_group                 |
| auth_group_permissions     |
| auth_permission            |
| auth_user                  |
| auth_user_groups           |
| auth_user_user_permissions |
| django_admin_log           |
| django_content_type        |
| django_migrations          |
| django_session             |
+----------------------------+
```

Following Django tutorial documentation, with slight modifications, I have these directories & files:

`Tree:`

```
...DB1-PROJECT
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───diet
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           __init__.cpython-311.pyc
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           admin.cpython-311.pyc
│           apps.cpython-311.pyc
│           models.cpython-311.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-311.pyc
│
└───mysite
    │   asgi.py
    │   settings.py
    │   urls.py
    │   wsgi.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
            settings.cpython-311.pyc
            urls.cpython-311.pyc
            wsgi.cpython-311.pyc
            __init__.cpython-311.pyc
```

`..\diet\models.py`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models


class Food(models.Model):
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'food'


class Gut(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    reaction_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'gut'


class Meal(models.Model):
    meal_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'meal'


class MealFood(models.Model):
    meal = models.OneToOneField(Meal, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'meal_food'
        unique_together = (('meal', 'food'),)


class Reaction(models.Model):
    reaction = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'reaction'
```

`...\mysite\settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'diet.apps.DietConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'diet_py',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Did you run python manage.py makemigrations? You need to run it first, and then python manage.py migrate. The migrations you have ran were created by Django by default.

Comment: Yikes! That I had not done. With that step I get the expected result. Kindly post that as an answer and I will eagerly accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after model code finished. you need to run makemigrations command in CLI

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

When you run this command you can see the modifications and additions that you are created in the command line some thing like following

```
diet/migrations/0001_initial.py
- Create model Food
```

if that not worked. The try the migrate command with app name as parameter like bellow

```
python manage.py makemigrations diet
```